# Getting end points of a line if I have middlepoint and angle and length

Tags: python, math

I have the angle of the line and middle point x,y and the length of the wanted line, how would i go forward to get the points x1,y1 and x2,y2 in order to use Cv2 to draw a line between the points ?

Comment: Using parametric form of line (google it) which relate line with angle and distance of segment, you can apply formula and calculate the next coordinates, and hence draw a line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my answer:

```
import cv2
import math
import numpy as np


img = np.zeros((200,200),dtype=np.uint8)
img = cv2.bitwise_not(img)
img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

angle = 45
angle = 180-angle
angle = angle/180*math.pi
midx,midy = (50,50)
length = 80

r = length/2

x1,y1 = int(midx+ r*math.cos(angle)), int(midy + r*math.sin(angle))
x2,y2 = int(midx-r*math.cos(angle)),int(midy - r*math.sin(angle))

print(x1,y1)
print(x2,y2)

cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,0,255),2)

cv2.imshow("line",img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Output:

```
21 78
78 21
```

[image: Output Image]

Parametric form : https://doubleroot.in/lessons/straight-line/parametric-form/

Answer (score 1):

Just use formula: x = r*cos(theta), y = r*sin(theta)

```py
import math

def line(x0, y0, angle, length):
    half_length = length/2
    radian = angle/180*math.pi
    dx = half_length*math.cos(radian)
    dy = half_length*math.sin(radian)
    return ((x0-dx, y0-dy), (x0+dx, y0+dy))
```